# How do matrices handle dividing by 0?

Tags: r, matrix

I ran into an unexpected (to me) behavior with how R (R-3.0.3) handles `Inf` within   a matrix.

```
scalar <- 1

mat1 <- matrix(0)
mat2 <- matrix(1)
mat2 <- -log(mat2)

# > mat1
#       [,1]
# [1,]    0
#
# > mat2
#       [,1]
# [1,]    0

(mat1[1,1] - scalar[1])/mat1[1,1]
# [1] -Inf

(mat2[1,1] - scalar[1])/mat2[1,1]
# [1] Inf
```

Why don't both give `-Inf`? I do not see anything the help file for `matrix`. I also could not tell a difference between `mat1` and `mat2` using `class`, `str` or `dput`.

Comment: I had a moment of doubt, but yeah, you're just doing `(-1) / -log(1)`. Why shouldn't that be `Inf`?

Comment: So R stores `-log(1)` instead of `0` in `mat2`? I do not understand why both calculations would not be `-1/0`?

Comment: The intricacies of IEEE arithmetic are.....intricate. I'm simply saying that it doesn't surprise me that `-log(1)` might result in a [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) under the hood.

Comment: I would just expect to get `-Inf` when I think I am calculating `-1/0`. The result makes determining the sign more work. Maybe the better question to ask is how `matrix` handles logs?

Comment: And you do...but you're doing `-1/-0`, and you get the corresponding result.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the matrix class. This is going to be a fundamental aspect of how R implements (almost certainly correctly) IEEE standards for doing arithmetic. The only solution is to work within those standards.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I see what you mean by a signed zero now. Thanks for your persistence. I would accept an answer if you want to post one.

Comment: `mat2 + 0` fixes the signed zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just summarize the discussion on the comments to close out the question.

First, this behavior is not specific to matrices, observe

```
a<- 0; (a-1)/a
# [1] -Inf

a<- -log(1); (a-1)/a
# [1] Inf
```

but rather is it a result of the intricacies of IEEE floating point arithmetic. Despite the fact that

```
-log(1) == 0
# [1] TRUE
```

zero can actually hold a sign. There is a "+0" and a "-0" and `-log(1)` returns the latter. Adding `+0` to a negative zero value should make it a "regular" zero.

```
a<- -log(1)+0; (a-1)/a
# [1] -Inf
```